# Implemeting multiprocessing queue with limited number of workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

Right now I have a working program that is monitoring a directory looking for a specifically named file. When the file appears in this directory, code is changing its name to something else and then exectues some functions on it in another process so that multiple files can be worked on in the same time (code below probably explains it better than my broken english). I need to change it in such a way that those files are added and stored in queue and I can limit the number of concurrently worked on files.

exemplary current code:

```py
Class WorkOnFiles(multiprocessing.Process):
   def __init__(self, filename):

   ...

   def run(self):
      #do something on files

directory = "/path/to/directory"

while True:
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      if filename.startswith("ABC"):
         new_filename = "XYZ" + filename
         os.system(f"mv {filename} {new_filename}")
         WorkOnFiles(new_filename).start()
```

I want new code to work similarly (preferably not to change "WorkOnFiles" class) but to restrict the number of concurrent processes and while those files are worked on, new files are added to some sort of queues waiting for thier turn. Something like this (below is broken pseudo-code just to show how I envision it could look like):

```py
workers = create_workers(num_of_workers = 2)
queue = make_queue()

while True:
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      if filename.startswith("ABC"):
         new_filename = "XYZ" + filename
         os.system(f"mv {filename} {new_filename}")
       
        
         queue.add(new_filename)

      if there is an idle worker and queue not empty:
         workers.run(WorkOnFiles(queue.get()).start())
      time.sleep(1)
```

So this code would make 2 workers - processes that can be run simultanously. Every second it would check if ABC file appeard, it would add its new name to queue and next if there is at least one idle worker and queue is not empty it would start a new process to work on this file.
I've tried different approaches but I can't really grasp how multiprocessing.queue and and multiprocessing package works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use **multiprocessing** in Python. A developer can fork a single process from the parent, usually to spin off a new worker process to handle an ad-hoc job. Or the developer can use the "pool" construct to manage several processes. And there are others, mostly in the standard Python `multiprocessing` module.

But in Python version 3.2, they introduced `concurrent.futures` and the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class therein. This in my experience this is the easiest way to manage multiple processes, and seems to be a good fit for your task, namely to 1) limit number of dedicated workers, and 2) queue up tasks. Both of these features are built into the executor class.

Here is an example of limiting a simple computation to *only two spawned processes* to work on an incoming stream of multiple tasks:

```
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor

def f(a):
    sleep(0.01)
    
executor = Executor(2)
for x in range(100):
    executor.submit(f, x)

executor.shutdown()
```

The above is a minimalistic example that you can apply to your code. Try timing the above program on your machine, then change the number of workers from 2 to 4 and compare the runtimes.

There's are more multiprocessing constructs inside Python's [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, and it's worth familiarizing with. In my opinion, this module makes it easier than ever before to spin up and manage multiple processes in Python for purposes of changing existing code to gain additional performance (given the hardware resources, of course).